# Why is the root password on Linux Mint my user password?

Tags: linux-mint, password, root, passwd

I did a fresh install of Linux Mint 18.1 and created a single user named  "jack" with PASSWORD1 as the password. Later, I changed the password (using the "Users and Groups" graphical dialog) to PASSWORD2. Both logging in and using `sudo` now require PASSWORD2, as expected.

However, PASSWORD1 is still the password for the account `root`. I can tell because `su -` and `su - root` reject PASSWORD2 but accept PASSWORD1.

Isn't this a security flaw? Why did the root account silently copy my user password in the first place? If I knew my password was compromised and changed it, I wouldn't think to check that the root account was still using the compromised password.

In fact, I thought the root account was disabled on Linux Mint by default. See this question for instance: https://superuser.com/questions/323317/why-does-linux-ubuntu-mint-lack-a-root-account

Any reason not to disable the root account using `sudo passwd -l root`? Why wasn't this done by default?

**Edits**

@terdon I am fairly sure that I never ran `sudo passwd` or even plain `passwd` on this operating system.

@Mark I checked and the only thing that comes back doesn't look relevant.

```
jack@gamma /var/log $ ls auth.log*
auth.log  auth.log.1  auth.log.2.gz  auth.log.3.gz  auth.log.4.gz

jack@gamma /var/log $ zgrep passwd auth.log*
auth.log.2.gz:Mar  9 17:56:07 gamma mdm[1695]: pam_succeed_if(mdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "jack"

jack@gamma /var/log $ zgrep "password changed" auth.log*
# nothing returned
```

Edit:
I have filed a bug report with Linux Mint
https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1675575

Now that @Roger Lipscombe has confirmed this issue, I am going to add a bounty to the question.

Comment: That does seem strange. Are you 100% sure you didn't active the root account by running `sudo passwd` after first installing but before changing passwords?

Comment: Along those lines, can you look in your `/var/log/auth.log` (and any older copies such as `auth.log.1`) for a line like `passwd[6434]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): password changed for root` ?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I've added this info to the question.

Comment: @terdon I've responded. So if I can verify this for sure on a fresh install do you think it's a bug I should report?

Comment: It turns out that I have exactly the same issue; Mint 17.1 upgraded to 17.3; As far as I know, I've never changed the root password.

Answer (score 8):

#### Mint 17.3

This looks like a deliberate decision in Linux Mint. I just freshly installed Mint 17.3 on a VM, and the root account has a password set in `/etc/shadow`. After changing my user password, `su -` accepts my previous user password.

I can't (yet) explain *why* though.

#### Mint 18.3

I've just done a fresh install of Mint 18.3, and I **don't** have a password set for my root account. `sudo grep root /etc/shadow` shows `!` in the password field, which [means that the account is locked](https://superuser.com/a/623882/4206).

Comment: So it sounds like you think this is a bug in Mint 17.3? Also can you explain what it means to have "!" in the password field?

Answer (score 3):

By default root password is your user password, I guess that the reason is that its a much more secure approach when the password will be the one that is set by you (assuming its a good - difficult to hack password) rather than some well known password like "root" that is always in place by default and known over the Internet (security risk).

There is a good discussion about the topic [*on linuxmint.com forum*](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=233818) - citing from there user karlchen:

> During the Linux mint installation, you create your first user account. You assing a password to this first user.
>   The installer silently assigns the same password to the user account root.
>   That is does do so can be found in the Official Linux Mint User Guide as well. (cf. e.g. p. 20)
>   So if you remember your initial user password, you know your root password as well.
>   In case you change your user password later on, doing so will not change the root password.

Source - page 20 last paragraph: [*https://www.linuxmint.com/documentation/user-guide/Cinnamon/english_18.0.pdf*](https://www.linuxmint.com/documentation/user-guide/Cinnamon/english_18.0.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the source! Does the source comment on whether the root password will be disabled by default?

Answer (score 3):

try to use *sudo -i* to get root with your own password

Comment: this worked for me in Linux Mint 20.1