# Verify password hash in bash script?

Tags: bash, password

*Related to [Why is the root password on Linux Mint my user password?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/352940/46851)*

It appears that my Mint 17.3 box has a root password set: I see a password hash in `/etc/shadow` (it starts with `$6$...`). I'd like to compare this password hash with my (known) user password.

For whatever reason, I don't trust `su -` (in the linked question) to not use *my* password, vs. the *root* password.

Is there a simple way (in bash, e.g.) to compare a known hash with a known password and see if they match?

Comment: Once I'd figured out that `$6$` means it's a SHA-512 hash, I found the answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/52108/46851

Comment: If you don't trust `su` to use the root password (which it should), then I must assume your machine is compromised in some way. Is that correct?

Comment: No. I'm not worried about compromise. I don't trust myself to not get confused between `su` and `sudo`. By taking them out of the equation, I can verify *only* the hash in `/etc/shadow`, without anything else in the way.

Comment: For example: it's _possible_ that there's a configuration setting that causes `su` to allow me to use my user password in the same way as `sudo` does. Is there? Probably not. But I don't _know for sure_.

Comment: No. I'm not planning on reimplementing `su`; that would be stupid. After the "Apple re-enables your root account without a password" thing today, I went looking to see if I _had_ a root password. To my surprise, I did. I found the other question ("Why is the root password on Linux Mint...?"). I was looking for a good way to _simply_ (i.e. no `su`, no `sudo`, no `ssh`) see what password the root account had. So: verify the hash.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe, ah, that makes sense, I looked at this from the wrong angle.

Comment: As for `su` accepting the users' own password... that's possible in principle: shadow-utils contains code for access control within `su`, through [`/etc/suauth`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/suauth.5.html), but it's disabled if PAM is used (which it is on Debian). I suppose something similar could be done with PAM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find the salt used in `/etc/shadow`, it's the characters between the second and third `$`, usually there will be eight.

Use `mkpasswd -m sha-512 -S <salt>`, and enter the password you think it's suposed to be when it asks. It will output the hash with `$6$<salt>$` prefixed.

Comment: It's `-m sha-512` (with the hyphen) on Mint 17.3; use `mkpasswd -m help` for the list.

Comment: That hyphen is also in the method name on my debian, and probably in general, so it was a typo, that I've fixed now.

Comment: I'll have to agree with the man page statement that claims it's _overfeatured_. It's a shame one can't just pass the salt in its already encoded form (like `$6$round=x$salt$` here) directly instead of having to pass the algorithm, salt and round as separate options for `mkpasswd` to reconstruct the `$6$round=x$salt$` salt passed to `crypt(3)`.

Comment: you need to install whois. `sudo apt install whois`

Answer (score 3):

In the end, you need to call the `crypt(3)` function from the `libcrypt` (which on GNU systems like Linux Mint comes with the GNU libc) with the password as first argument and the hash (`$6$...`) as second argument.

`python` is one such tool that exposes that function, so you can do:

```
HASH='$6$...' python2 -c 'import crypt, os, getpass
print(crypt.crypt(getpass.getpass(), os.environ["HASH"]))'
```

And if the output matches the hash, that was the right password.

`$HASH` above can be either the full hash (like `$6$rounds=1234$somesalt$6eFBNhSgwEwdfZBHueBedpcqaVKGcV2DJy/tQMFd3JL88hwvgTkISJShnOUrbtP1fRs8I9rGIdsgWCoiujxD2/`) or just the part of it up to the rightmost `$`, that is including the salt and optional round count (`$6$rounds=1234$somesalt$`).

Or you can do the verification in `python`:

```
HASH='$6$...' python2 -c '
import crypt, os, getpass
hash = os.environ["HASH"]
if crypt.crypt(getpass.getpass(), hash) == hash:
  print "OK"
else:
  print "Wrong password"'
```

(then obviously, `$HASH` has to contain the full hash).

With `python`, you can also call functions from arbitrary libraries using the `ctypes` module. So another way to call the system's `crypt()` function (not that you'd need to as `crypt` is one of the standard modules, it's just that I was earlier under the impression that the `crypt` module came with its own separate `crypt()` implementation) is with  something like:

```
HASH='$6$...' python2 -c '
from ctypes import *
import os, getpass
l = CDLL("libcrypt.so.1")
l.crypt.restype = c_char_p
print l.crypt(getpass.getpass(), os.environ["HASH"])'
```

Answer (score 0):

`ssh root@localhost` comes to mind, though your distribution may have disabled password-based login for root entirely and/or installed a keypair; or logging in on your usual graphical login screen as user `root`. (Even if you have automatic login enabled, the shutdown dialog may offer to login as another user.)